How to reuse a "closure generator" in C++?
I've known one problem that closures do not behave like other programming languages (who expands the lifetime of captured variables and have GC) in C++
if we write a code like this
auto generator() {
  int common = 0;
  auto adder1 = [=]() mutable {
    ++common;
    return common;
  };
  auto adder2 = [=]() mutable {
    ++common;
    return common;
  };
  return make_pair(adder1, adder2);
}

int main() {
  auto pair = generator();
  auto a1 = pair.first;
  auto a2 = pair.second;
  cout << a1() << " " << a2() << "\n";
  return 0;
}

we are expected to get 1 2, for that the common is the "lexical environment" for both adder1 and adder2. However, we'll get 1 1, because common is copied by value, not by reference.
A solution to this problem is to let common be a static one. But in my perspective, the static does extend the lifetime of common in a way we don't want. (Maybe I have some misunderstanding). So I would rather use another solution using another closure and initialized lambda captures (in C++14) to generate the adders, capturing common by reference.
auto generator = [common = 0]() mutable {
  auto adder1 = [&]() {
    ++common;
    return common;
  };
  auto adder2 = [&]() {
    ++common;
    return common;
  };
  return make_pair(adder1, adder2);
};

this time it works well and output 1 2.
We use a function to initialize the adders, like the generator above. In general, they are not "closures" or at least not the closure specifically wanted. That's why I regard them as "closure generators".
Even it seemed to work well in the second edition, the generator does not create different commons for different (adder1, adder2) pairs. If we call generator like this:
int main() {
  auto pair1 = generator(); auto pair2 = generator();
  auto a1 = pair1.first; auto a2 = pair1.second;
  auto a3 = pair2.first; auto a4 = pair2.second;
  a1(); a1(); a1(); a2(); a2(); a2(); a2(); a3(); a4();
  cout << a1() << " " << a2() << " " << a3() << " " << a4() << "\n";
  return 0;
}

it will output 10 11 12 13 but not 8 9 3 4. Because the generator itself is a closure, hence the common assigned to pair1 and pair2 is the same one.
So I'm wondering whether there exists a way in C++ enabling us to reuse the "generator", no matter whether it is a closure or not.
An implementation without pointer is prefered. Thanks.

You are viewing lambdas from the wrong perspective. C++ is not other languages.There is no "lexical environment", there are objects, references and memory management. If you want two lambdas to share a single object and still have the memory management be correct, just do the first snippet but replace common with a std::shared_ptr.

Your lambdas capture variables by value. That means each lambda will get a copy of the value in the common variable. Then the generator function ends, and the life-time of the common variable ends, so you can't capture by reference either, unless you come up with a way to prolong the life-time of common.

Note that using a reference to a local variable that has expired is undefined behavior . "Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."

"a way in C++ enabling us to reuse the "generator"..." Not clear what this means. What is the expected output for a given input.

You had to add [=] and mutable to get the independent increments in the first version.  How can you still then say that you “expect[] to get 1 2”?

@user12002570，Thanks for your reply, in the last case I'm desired to get 8 9 3 4. I expect pair1 and pair2 to be "different closures", that is to say, the adder1 of pair1 and the adder1 of pair2 to increment separately, to their own copy of common. As a result, there are 2 commons and each of them have adder1  and adder2. 4 closures in total

@PasserBy Thanks! "two lambdas to share a single object" is what I want

@miyou379 You can use the decltype([](){}) trick as shown in my answer

generator stores state common and should be an object, so that C++ can manage the lifetime of that state. Consider just:
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
class generator {
    int common = 0;
    int get() { return ++common; }
public:
    std::function<int()> first = std::bind(&generator::get, this);
    std::function<int()> second = std::bind(&generator::get, this);
};

int main() {
  auto pair = generator(); // lifetime of common begins
  auto a1 = pair.first;
  auto a2 = pair.second;
  std::cout << a1() << " " << a2() << "\n";
  return 0; // lifetime of common ends
}

You can also manage lifetime differently. As you noted, you can make the lifetime static. You could also use dynamic allocation or use std::shared_ptr to extend the lifetime. I think the lifetime of common should be bind to the lifetime of the pair - thus, it is an object that contains both the pair of functions and common.


I'm desired to get 8 9 3 4 . "two lambdas to share a single object" is what I want

You can use the decltype([](){}) trick by making generated a templated entity and using in its default argument as shown below:
//made this a template
template<typename T> 
auto generator = [common = 0]() mutable {
  //same code here as before
  return make_pair(adder1, adder2);
};
//helper function template
template<typename T = decltype([](){})>
auto generator_t()
{
     return generator<T>();
}
int main() { 
  auto pair1 = generator_t(); auto pair2 = generator_t();
  //same code here as before
  cout << a1() << " " << a2() << " " << a3() << " " << a4() << "\n"; //prints 8 9 3 4 
  return 0;
}

Working demo

I'm not familiar with this 'trick' and I don't understand what it does.  Do you have a link to an explanation?

@melston Basically it uses the fact that each lambda has a distinct type from any other lambda. That should clear up what this does. I use it regularly when I need to create distinct types. I don't think the trick has a name. Maybe we can invent one since I use it regularly. Up for suggestions.

Are you saying that the lambdas have a distinct type even though the type is the same (the decltype is the same)?

@melston Yes exactly. You can check this by static_assert or simply by adding a static variable as in this  demo. Each time you call with the function with default argument in this demo, you get distinct types!

Thanks @user12002570.  That is interesting.  I don't understand how that happens since the type parameter is the same, though.  Where can I find some further information about this?

@melston Just to make it a little simpler, each time we call the above function template without any template argument, the default argument which is decltype[](){} will be used. That is say we type f<>() then this is equivalent to writing f<decltype([](){})> which I'm sure you already know. Similarly, if we now call again like f<>() same thing will happen the decltype([](){})  will be used meaning that another distinct type has been passed. One question is Why design a language with unique anonymous types?

Ahh.  Thanks.  I wasn't aware of the unique anonymous types constraint.
